# what does IB do behind the scene when I link IBoutlets/IBActions?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, interface-builder

I am new to mac dev, xcode and IB etc. I understand how to build simple applications and basic dragging & dropping in IB, but i don't know what and where does IB do with the objects.

the second questions is how to write a MVC without using IB?

Comment: Hi! I have 2 years of experience working with iPhone apps. We dropped using interface builder whatsoever, because when you build bigger solutions it only complicates things. Write the code and you'll have complete control ;) you can learn more about mvc here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html

Answer (score 2):

When you connect two objects in IB with `IBOutlet` or `IBAction` it creates some special tags in XIB (which is XML).

When bundle (**update**: sorry, it's not a bundle, but `UINib`) reads NIB (which is compiled XIB) it looks for such tags and objects they are refer. After that:

- For outlets it uses KVC (Key-Value Coding) to set corresponding property of receiving object.
- For actions it calls `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` on control object.

You can build iPhone app of any complexity without IB by creating and setting up objects in your code, but in most cases it's just not wise.

Further reading - [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the XIB files from IB are some kind of archives with your objects and their properties stored in them. When you send `-initWithNibName`, the objects are unarchived. So basically, you could - if you knew how - create your own XIB files and they should work. Note that loading a `UIViewController` without specifying a XIB file, an XIB file with the same name as your class is loaded. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder).

To your second question: You can create any object you add using IB programmatically. Typically, these are `UIView` subclasses that you initialize using `initWithFrame:`. Then you set the properties you need. Finally, you add them to your view using `addSubview`. 
`IBActions` are basically [Target/Action Pairs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html). If you for instance add `UIBarButtonItem`, you use `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:`. Setting the action is equal to setting an `IBAction` connection in IB.

You should be able to create any User Interface you want programmatically, however it's usually a lot of work compared to when using IB.